Ansible copy and synchronize alternatives when copy is slow and rsync is not installed on remote server
I have around 1K servers that I need to run these three commands:
#!/usr/bin/bash

ansible all -m shell -a 'mkdir -pv /root/newimages/'
ansible all -m copy -a 'src=/root/file1.tar dest=/root/newimages/ mode=644'
ansible all -m copy -a 'src=/root/file2.tar dest=/root/newimages/ mode=644'
ansible all -m copy -a 'src=/root/file3.tar dest=/root/newimages/ mode=644'
# until file100.tar
ansible all -m shell -a 'find /root/newimages/ -name "*.tar" -exec docker load -i {} \;'

Before starting, I know having multiple -m copy fileN.tar is good, but I couldn't find how to copy *.tar file with ansible command line inventory.
When I try copy module, it's too slow. When I try synchronize module, the issue is some of the servers return error that rsync command not found.
Since all of the servers do not have public internet access, I cannot install rsync via apt or yum. I also tried downloading the rsync.rpm file, but it requires a lot of dependencies, so I ignored installing it at the moment.
Are there any other solutions rather than copy and synchronize with the mentioned conditions?

how about scp? when you can reach them via ssh, you likely can via scp

@StefanHegny thanks. I thought I can use sftp for servers not having rsync. But it seems rsync is much faster than any of other commands like scp and sftp. I'm going to use sftp manually for those servers without rsync.

@Saeed - how do you do patch-management on your servers?

The documentation says: The ansible.builtin.copy module copies a file or a directory structure from the local or remote machine to a location on the remote machine. So you can copy a file or a folder.  If you can't copy the entire directory you could have three tasks in a playbook. One task to get a list of the files. Second task would be the copy task that would use the file list. The third task would be your shell command.

You would NOT need a task to create the directory because the documentation says: If dest is a non-existent path and if either dest ends with “/” or src is a directory, dest is created.

It is highly unlikely that rsync is any faster than scp or sftp. Unless the files already exist on the destination, they all have to transfer the same number of bytes, and they all are using ssh as the underlying transport.

Since the file is a Bash script, I assume there is nothing what prevents to write a small playbook for the Use Case?

@larsks rsync uses rolling checksums to exploit the internal redundancy of files and minimize the amount of data to transfer. So, if the files are highly redundant, it is very likely that rsync is faster than scp or sftp. You can test it yourself: concatenate 100 copies of a picture file in a single larger file, and time the transfers with rsync, ssh or sftp. You will likely see a significant difference, even when the file does not exist yet on the remote side.

Q: "Alternatives when copy is slow and rsync is not installed on Remote Server?"
According Ansible: How to optimize running speed of a playbook?

create, transfer, and unpack an archive(s)

In other words, in such a Use Case it is recommended to use the unarchive module – Unpacks an archive after (optionally) copying it from the local machine.

Example
Creating some test files via
for i in {1..9} ; do dd if=/dev/random of=tars/${i}.tar bs=4k iflag=fullblock,count_bytes count=10M ; done
tar cvzf tars/files.tar.gz tars/*.tar

and with a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Copy single files to Remote Node
    copy:
      src: "tars/{{ item }}.tar"
      dest: "/tmp"
      mode: 0644
    loop: "{{ range(1, 10, 1) }}"

  - name: Copy directoy to Remote Node
    copy:
      src: "tars/"
      dest: "/tmp/tars/"
      mode: 0644

  - name: Copy all files archived to Remote Node
    copy:
      src: "tars/files.tar.gz"
      dest: "/tmp"
      mode: 0644

  - name: Unarchive from Control Node into Remote Node
    unarchive:
      src: "tars/files.tar.gz"
      dest: "/tmp"
      mode: 0644
      extra_opts: [--strip-components=1, --overwrite]

the runtime looks like
TASK [Copy single files to Remote Node] ***************
changed: [test.example.com] => (item=1)
...
changed: [test.example.com] => (item=9)
(0:00:18.602)      

TASK [Copy directoy to Remote Node] *******************
changed: [test.example.com]
(0:00:13.484)

TASK [Copy all files archived to Remote Node] *********
changed: [test.example.com]
(0:00:04.680)

TASK [Unarchive from Control Node into Remote Node] ***
changed: [test.example.com]
(0:00:05.471)

=======================================================
Copy single files to Remote Node --------------- 18.60s
Copy directoy to Remote Node ------------------- 13.48s
Copy all files archived to Remote Node ---------- 4.68s
Unarchive from Control Node into Remote Node ---- 5.47s

